# Dealing Synchronous Request in Asynchronous Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous

## Problem

I am trying to convert my synchronous code to an asynchronous implementation. Using `aiohttp` I was able to almost get where I want. My problem is how to deal with *synchronous* requests. I have 3 types of functions:

1. Take argument, make *one* request (easy to turn async)
2. Take argument, make *multiple, independent* requests (easy to turn async as requests are independent)
3. Take argument, make *multiple, dependent* requests (problematic because I need to wait for the first response before making the second request)

I managed to come up with something but I am uncertain whether the two requests in `async_file.f2` are done synchronously (that is the second has to wait for the first to yield a response). Also, further constructive criticism is always welcomed.

## Code

`Python 3.8.0 [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win 32`

**master**

```py
master = {
    "f0": {
        "a": {
            "url": "https://example.com",
            "method": "get"
        }
    },
    "f1": {
        "a": {
            "url": ["https://example.com", "https://example.com"],
            "method": ["get", "get"]
        }
    },
    "f2": {
        "a": {
            "url": ["https://example.com", "https://example.com"],
            "method": ["post", "get"]
        }
    }
}
```

**sync_file**

```
import requests
from typing import List

from master import master


def f0(key: str) -> str:
    method = master["f0"][key]["method"]
    url = master["f0"][key]["url"]
    return requests.request(method, url).text


def f1(key: str) -> List[str]:
    method_0, method_1 = master["f1"][key]["method"]
    url_0, url_1 = master["f1"][key]["url"]
    return [requests.request(method_0, url_0).text, requests.request(method_1, url_1).text]


def f2(key: str) -> str:
    method_0, method_1 = master["f2"][key]["method"]
    url_0, url_1 = master["f2"][key]["url"]
    response = requests.request(method_0, url_0)
    return requests.request(method_1, url_1, data=response.text).text


def main(key: str):
    res = []
    for f in (f0, f1, f2):
        res.append(f(key=key))
    return res


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = main("a")
    print(f"test: [{', '.join(type(_).__name__ for _ in test)}]")
    # test: [str, list, str]
```

**async_file**

```py
import aiohttp
import asyncio
from typing import List

from master import master

async def f0(key: str) -> str:
    method = master["f0"][key]["method"]
    url = master["f0"][key]["url"]
    session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
    print('f0: request', flush=True)
    async with session.request(method, url) as response:
        text = await response.text()
    print('f0: response', flush=True)
    await session.close()
    return text

async def f1(key: str) -> List[str]:
    method_0, method_1 = master["f1"][key]["method"]
    url_0, url_1 = master["f1"][key]["url"]
    session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
    print('f1: request', flush=True)
    async with session.request(method_0, url_0) as response:
        text_0 = await response.text()
    print('f1: response', flush=True)
    print('f1: request', flush=True)
    async with session.request(method_1, url_1) as response:
        text_1 = await response.text()
    print('f1: response', flush=True)
    await session.close()
    return [text_0, text_1]


async def f2(key: str) -> str:
    method_0, method_1 = master["f2"][key]["method"]
    url_0, url_1 = master["f2"][key]["url"]
    session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
    print('f2: request', flush=True)
    async with session.request(method_0, url_0) as response:
        text_0 = await response.text()
    print('f2: response', flush=True)
    print('f2: request', flush=True)
    async with session.request(method_1, url_1, data=text_0) as response:
        text_1 = await response.text()
    print('f2: response', flush=True)
    await session.close()
    return text_1


async def run(key: str):
    tasks = []
    for f in (f0, f1, f2):
        task = asyncio.ensure_future(f(key))
        tasks.append(task)
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


def main(key: str):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    future = asyncio.ensure_future(run(key))
    return loop.run_until_complete(future)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = main("a")
    print(f"test: [{', '.join(type(_).__name__ for _ in test)}]")
    # test: [str, list, str]
```

Comment: Welcome, why `f0, f1, f2 ...` ? Is that pseudo-code, meaning that all reviewers are prevented (should ignore) from pointing to naming issues?

Comment: Hi @RomanPerekhrest, yes, I used these generic names for simplicity - pointing to naming issues may be omitted.

Comment: What's your Python version?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I'm running `Python 3.8.0 on win 32`